# Create session mutex from a service?

Tags: windows, object, mutex

Consider: *[Mutex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)* (MSDN)

(And using WinObj from Sysinternals.)

How do I create a mutex for a session other than the one creating it?

I.e. From a system service in session 0, create a mutex in session 1?

I have attempted creating the mutex using

\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\myName

But that fails.

Is it possible to write directly to the root of the Windows object namespace shown in WinObj?

Comment: A session object can only be created by a process running in that session, at least from user mode; I don't know whether or not you could do this in a kernel driver.  But why would you want to do this?  It is not good behavior to go messing around with sessions other than your own.

Comment: I want to programmatically access and create mutants in sessions for users, from a system service. I don't understand why this should not be possible. Indeed I can can CreateProcessAsUser to inject a process into the user's session to do these tasks on behalf of my service which gives me the same effect. I would prefer to directly manipulate the objects from the service if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try use "Global\" prefix in your mutex name. On a server that is running Terminal Services, a named system mutex can have two levels of visibility. If its name begins with the prefix "Global\", the mutex is visible in all terminal server sessions.

Or maybe you can try another approach. Instead of mutual exclusion try use [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [OpenFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366791%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) methods with "Global\" prefix in name.